# Recycling WCF Web Service on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

Is it possible to recycle a WCF web service hosted on IIS from code?

When a certain error code is received from an Oracle connection I am using, I want to recycle the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you jus want to recycle your current application then try

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

it will unload your app from host's memory and will load again on next request.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx)

> UnloadAppDomain is useful for servers that have a large number of
>   applications that infrequently receive requests. Rather than keep
>   application resources alive for the lifetime of the process,
>   UnloadAppDomain allows programmatic shutdown of unused applications.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I needed. Now I can make sure that my Oracle connection is completely disconnected when I receive the error message. Thanks.