# What's a general way to provide an emergency mode for a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a iPad which is using WCF service.

The WCF service is loading some background data for every 10 seconds.
Sometimes background loading process fail and all the data and service methods become dysfunctional.

How can I provide a 'kill switch' to take every mobile service method down and provide a brief message (or send a mail) automatically when being called?

Is it possible to implement in the service setting or should I do something else?

Comment: You could add a `Global Application Class` file to handle the startup/requests to the service, and keep a static var to track when something goes wrong. When the static is set you can just pass back some blank data or throw the appropriate exception in any subsequent service calls

Comment: How are you hosting the WCF service?

Comment: @PeterRitchie:    hosting on IIS as website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find your WCF service is in an bad state, you can call `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain`.  See also [Recycling WCF Web Service on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816983/recycling-wcf-web-service-on-iis)